# How to test OpenCV DNN module accuracy? It does not predict correct detections for YOLOv3. Whereas Darknet detector detects correctly

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, neural-network, yolo

OpenCV DNN module does not predict correct detections for YOLOv3. Whereas the Darknet detector detects correctly.

System information (version)

- OpenCV => 4.2.1 and 4.4.x
- Operating System / Platform => Ubuntu 18.04 64Bit

I tested results with compiled OpenCV from source code and I tried with pre-built opencv-python also but OpenCV DNN detects wrong objects.

Whereas Darknet detector detects correctly.

Correct detection with darknet detector:
[image]

Wrong detection with OpenCV DNN module:
[image]

YOLOv3 network and model weights are from https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

- modelWeights: `yolov3.weights`
- modelConfiguration: `yolov3.cfg`
- ClassesFile: `coco.names`

**Detailed description**

Please see the output images at the link appended below. (correct detection with **darknet detector**)
compared with the wrong detection (with **OpenCV DNN**)

Output images available in this [Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DKmnDcFpoFWxPDCUAvyaXhebG9lleYJ4?usp=sharing).

The above link includes test-images also for steps to test

```py
    # The following code is partial to demonstrate steps 
    net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights)
    layerNames = net.getLayerNames()
    layerNames = [layerNames[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
    
    # construct a blob from the input frame and then perform a forward pass of the YOLO object detector, 
    # giving us our bounding boxes and associated probabilities
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),
        swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    layerOutputs = net.forward(layerNames)
    
    # initialize our lists of detected bounding boxes, confidences,
    # and class IDs, respectively
    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    classIDs = []
 
    # loop over each of the layer outputs
    for output in layerOutputs:
        # loop over each of the detections
        for detection in output:
            # extract the class ID and confidence (i.e., probability)
            # of the current object detection
            scores = detection[5:]
            classID = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[classID]
 
            # filter out weak predictions by ensuring the detected
            # probability is greater than the minimum probability
            if confidence > args["confidence"]:
                # scale the bounding box coordinates back relative to
                # the size of the image, keeping in mind that YOLO
                # actually returns the center (x, y)-coordinates of
                # the bounding box followed by the boxes' width and
                # height
                box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
                (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")
 
                # use the center (x, y)-coordinates to derive the top
                # and and left corner of the bounding box
                x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
                y = int(centerY - (height / 2))
 
                # update our list of bounding box coordinates,
                # confidences, and class IDs
                boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                classIDs.append(classID)
                
 
    # apply non-maxima suppression to suppress weak, overlapping
    # bounding boxes
    idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, args["confidence"], args["threshold"])
    
    dets = []
    if len(idxs) > 0:
        # loop over the indexes we are keeping
        for i in idxs.flatten():
            (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
            (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])
            dets.append([x, y, x+w, y+h, confidences[i]])
    
    if len(boxes) > 0:
        i = int(0)
        for box in boxes:
            # extract the bounding box coordinates
            (x, y) = (int(box[0]), int(box[1]))
            (w, h) = (int(box[2]), int(box[3]))
 
            # draw a bounding box rectangle and label on the image
            # color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
            # cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
            color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[indexIDs[i] % len(COLORS)]]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (w, h), color, 2)
     
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, color, 2)# 1.0 0.5, color, 2)
            i += 1
 
    cv2.imwrite("detection-output.jpg", frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your detection is correct, since all of your labels is car, the problem is the text you have in this line:

```
cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, color, 2)
```

you should put the class name in the text but i cant find where the `text` is defined. your code should be like this :

```
cv2.putText(frame, classes[class_ids[index]], (x + 5, y + 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, colors,2)
```

but in my experience , darknet has better detection than opencv dnn.

Comment: Thanks @Amir Karami. This code is brief and partial to show the steps I have taken to get detection in output of OpenCV DNN, after forward pass on the network `layerNames`. There is no issue with `text`. The `text` variable is updated with classes in a loop. Yolo Model is also OK. 

The problem is with the wrong detection in output of OpenCV DNN module in `for detection in output:` loop, and my question is How to test detection accuracy of OpenCV DNN?

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/17621#issuecomment-647691042 <--- OpenCV DNN performance is identical to Darknet performance. The differences are mostly due to NMS.

Comment: @Zach You can use [this script](https://gist.github.com/YashasSamaga/077a1d69c48e4cdb9957d167b7000b98) for mAP calculation.